# SharePoint 2019 on premise - Analytics not working correctly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, audit-log-reports, popularity-trends

We have had no success with gleaning any decent analytical reports from our SP2019 on premise system.
We can currently see under the global search the views on a page but we cannot see where to find this value and have it broken down into weeks, months etc.

The only other report we can glean is a usage report which has very non-specific measures in it - just a broad count of users in the last week, month etc.

Would this indicate we are not setup for analytical reports? We are looking for the reports under the site - Popularity and Search Reports.

If someone could point us in the right direction for getting this checked and correct.

Answer (score 1):

We are able to answer our own question here.

Our Reporting feature was previously activated:
Site Settings >   Site collection features > Reporting as well as Reports and Data Search Support

We had not set up our Audit log report - setup is now complete
[image]

And also discovered that all of our document libraries we wanted to include in the reports were not setup to do so: Found under Document Library > Settings > Information management policy settings

[image]

Located under our Document Master Content in this case we were able to activate the Auditing of these documents.

For our purposes the Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties.

We do hope this helps someone else - we did find the locating of this information a little disjointed in discovery.